# Is it posible to intercept a Spock feature's execution just prior to the evaluation of a feature's cleanup block?

Tags: groovy, spock

Is there any way for a custom Spock annotation to intercept a feature's execution prior to the execution of each `cleanup` block? I realize that I can intercept prior to the execution of the spec's `cleanup()` method, but I was hoping to intercept the feature prior to the content of the `cleanup` block running.

For example:

```
class Extension extends AbstractAnnotationDrivenExtension<Extension>{

  @Override
  void visitSpec(SpecInfo s){
    s.addCleanupInterceptor(new Inter())
  }

}
```

```
class Inter implements IMethodInterceptor{

  @Override
  void intercept(IMethodInvocation inv){
    println inv.getMethod().getKind()
    inv.proceed()
  }

}
```

```
@CatchErrors
class SampleTest extends Specification {

  def "A sample feature"(){
    when:
    foo()

    then:
    false 

    cleanup:
    println "In cleanup block"
    bar()

  }
}
```

Which outputs: `In cleanup block \n CLEANUP`

In the above example, I want to intercept prior to the execution of that final `cleanup` block. I have attempted to register interceptor via `addCleanupInterceptor` when I'm in `visitSpec()`, but to no avail. I don't seem to hit this interceptor until after all blocks of the feature have been executed, instead of before bar() is run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. This has been requested before in [Spock issue #538](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/538), but has not been implemented yet. Even with Spock 2.0 (based on JUnit 5 Jupiter and compatible with Groovy 3) in front of the door (milestone 2 build has been released a while ago), this feature does not seem to be planned for the release.

Comment: Ah, that is unfortunate. Thanks for the answer and the issue link!